# A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_contacts'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Ali Ahmad\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_contacts-1.1.7+1\android\build.gradle' line: 34
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_contacts'.

> Could not find method namespace() for arguments [co.quis.flutter_contacts] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I want to resolve it